# How to monitor the installation process through java program?

Tags: java, installanywhere

I need help on keeping track of the Installation process through java code. Our installers are developed by using the InstallAnywhere. When the user clicks cancel button the Installer quits but does not leave the system in a cleaned state as before the installation. So kindly help me in tracking of the 'Cancel' button by the user so that we can perform some opertaions which will leave the system in a cleaned state.

Kindly suggest me the approaches that i can take to resolve this problem. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to figure out how to do this within the InstallAnywhere framework.  If I recall, it provides a lot of hooks for doing things via plugin Java classes, especially with the Enterprise edition.  The documentation is pretty extensive, and should give you some clues about how to proceed.

If that approach doesn't work, and you cannot get any help from the InstallAnywhere support channels, forums, etc, consider switching to an Open Source java installer.

Answer (score 0):

InstallAnyWhere must have documentation about it.